# Centering multiple images

Tags: horizontal-alignment

If I try to center multiple images, as below, the first image has a small indent. Can anyone tell me why?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label = 6.\theenumi]
\item \hfill
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale = .75]{611}
\captionof{figure}{}
\includegraphics[scale = .75]{612}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This outputs the following: [image]

Comment: Did you run that exact example? Please provide a minimal working example, that lets us reproduce the problem, and helps you in figuring out whats going on.

Comment: That example code has two unclosed environments (`enumerate` and `center`).

Comment: Sorry, I'll update it.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, besides removing the indent? Your code is more than unusual.

Comment: You shouldn't have `\hfill` after `\item` and you shouldn't surround the `\item` in another environment such as `center`?

Comment: Whoops, got rid of the second `\item` beyond that, I guess I'm just not a savvy LaTeX user.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard to guess the intention of the posted code and it's very unusual to have a figure in an `enumerate` but anyway something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label = 6.\theenumi]
\item \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\centering
\includegraphics[scale = .75,valign=t]{example-image-golden}
\captionof{figure}{}
\includegraphics[scale = .75]{example-image-golden}
\captionof{figure}{}
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```